# Создание RESTful Web-сервиса Spring

Tags: java, spring

друзья! Изучаю Spring, создал restful web-service на Spring и разбираю в данный момент приложение, но не пойму где находится: {"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}   -  JSON строка, где она находится в проекте? Объясните пожалуйста! Вот ссылка на проект: http://spring-projects.ru/guides/rest-service/#scratch .У меня точь-в-точь, всё работает, но не пойму где находится JSON строка, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нигде она не находится, она создаётся Jackson-mapperом из экземляра Greeting, который вы возвращаете из контроллера.

Вот же код:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Вы отправляете GET-запрос, который допускает один параметр - `name`. Если этот параметр не передается, то по умолчанию он равен строке `World` (в `@RequestParam` всё это указано). `counter` - просто переменная-счётчик. Соответственно, если вы при запуске отправляете пустой GET, то у вас вызовется конструктор `new Greeting(1, "Hello, World!")` и контроллер вернет этот объект. Далее, чтобы преобразовать объект в тело ответа используется Json-mapper, по умолчанию в спринге это Jackson. Собственно, по вашей ссылке описано всё то, что я тут написал.

То есть для вас ваша Json строка как бы автоматически строится из экземляра `Greeting`, но под капотом на самом деле работает другой класс, который как раз делает строку из экземляра. В случае передачи более сложных конструкций часто приходится писать свои реализации мапперов, или отдельные реализации сериализаторов для отдельных классов.